# How to prevent compiz spam in journalctl due to wine

Tags: ubuntu, wine, compiz, journalctl

I run a program (DingTalk) in Wine on Ubuntu, and because there are some lingering compatibility issues I find a lot of error messages about `compiz` in `journalctl`. There are several errors every second.

The issues are not bad enough to prevent me from using the program, but the spammy error messages fill up a lot of disk space, causing older logs to very quickly get deleted to prevent my drive from filling up. I've already allowed several GB of storage for journal files and don't want to just give it more space to fill with the error messages.

Is it possible to configure things so that these `compiz` errors do not get logged to the journal? I don't know if this is a configuration to be made in `compiz`, or in Wine.

System details:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- wine-8.21 (Staging)
- Compiz 0.9.14.1

Examples of these errors:

Mostly it is one of these, spammed frequently:

```
0078:fixme:icon:NtUserDrawIconEx Error retrieving icon frame 0
04f0:fixme:virtual:NtQueryVirtualMemory (0x3b24,(nil),info_class=1,0x7f10f538c630,32784,(nil)) Unknown information class
ERROR 2023-12-09 15:11:22 unity.decoration.shape DecorationsShape.cpp:78 Failed to get shape rectangles
08ac:fixme:gdiplus:GdipWidenPath unimplemented dash cap 2
006c:fixme:mountmgr:harddisk_query_volume Unsupported volume query 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my own problem. I was finally able to prevent the logging with these steps:

1. Use `pidof compiz` to find the process ID of `compiz`
2. `sudo systemctl status [the PID]` to find the service that is running compiz. For me running this pulled up `user@1000.service`.
3. Scroll down the `CGroup` section to find the user-level service running `compiz`. For me, this was `unity7.service`.
4. `systemctl --user [the user-level service]`. This will show the location of the `.service` file after `Loaded:`
5. Add `StandardOutput=null` and `StandardError=null` after `[Service]` inside the corresponding `.service` file.